# How to implement a BroadcastReceiver in Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to implement a BroadcastReceiver but it is not working.
I want to use it to return progress from a class that implements network io, which is called from an AsyncTask inside my Activity.

Here is the code for my activity:

```
package com.ClinicalInterface;

public class TestActivity extends ListActivity {

    static AsyncDataLoader mAsyncDataLoader;
    static ProgressDialog dialog;
    static ArrayList<String> list;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        dialog.show();
        mAsyncDataLoader = new AsyncDataLoader();
        mAsyncDataLoader.execute();  
     }

    public class AsyncDataLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {        

        public class mTestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
            @Override 
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
                System.out.println( "I've received something!" );
                publishProgress(2);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground( Void ... params ) {            
            TestLoader tl = new TestLoader();
            tl.setContext(getApplicationContext());
            tl.setServeraddress("192.168.2.109");
            list = tl.doLST(null);
            return "COMPLETE!";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            if (values[0] == 2) {
                dialog.setMessage("Loading data ...");
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            dialog.dismiss();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(TestActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, list);
            TestActivity.this.setListAdapter(adapter);                     
        }
    }         
}
```

This is supposed to display a list, then overlay this with a progress dialog while the data for the list is returned from a server. And this works OK.
I would like to update the text in the progress dialog as the network io is done.
This is the code that implements the network io:

```
package com.ClinicalInterface;

public class TestLoader {
    private Context mContext;

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

     public ArrayList<String> doLST(String arg) {

         // Send intent to AsyncTask         
         Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, mTestReceiver.class);
         intent.setAction("PROGRESS");
         mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
         System.out.println( "message sent" );

         // Code that actually does network io removed for brevity
    }
}
```

In the Android manifest file I've added the following:

```
<activity android:name="TestActivity" android:label="TestActivity">
    <receiver android:name=".AsyncDataLoader.mTestReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROGRESS" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</activity>
```

I get the log print "message sent"
But not the log print "I've received something"

I am an Android newbie so I assume I've not implemented something correctly. 
Any ideas?

Original post updated with intent-filter and set of action when creating the intent. Still not working.

Comment: So your Broadcast Receiver should be launched when you recieve a message?

Comment: No. The receiver should receive the intent when its sent. And its sent when DoLST is called.
And once I have got the intent sent once I can then send it multiple times as the network io progresses - and then I can use it to update the ui with calls to publishProgress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok
It seems like the answer is that its not possible to use the manifest to register the receiver.
If I change the code so that it uses registerReceiver then it works ok.
Code updated like this:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground( Void ... params ) {            
    TestLoader tl = new TestLoader();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("PROGRESS");
    mReceiver mmReceiver = new mReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mmReceiver, intentFilter);            
    tl.setContext(getApplicationContext());
    tl.setServeraddress("192.168.2.109");
    list = tl.doLST(null);
    unregisterReceiver(mmReceiver);
    return "COMPLETE!";
}
```

And remove anything to do with the receiver from the manifest.

Note: the code that sends the Broadcast is like this:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setAction("PROGRESS");
 mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your [`<receiver>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html) tag needs to contain an [`<intent-filter>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) to tell Android which broadcast intents you actually want to receive.

**EDIT:**

An `Intent` is not much more than a container for a message; it's the function that you call to send the `Intent` that determines which fields you need to set.

From the docs for `Intent`:

> [`Intent`] can be used with `startActivity` to launch an `Activity`, `broadcastIntent` to send it to **any** interested `BroadcastReceiver` components, and `startService(Intent)` or `bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int)` to communicate with a background `Service`.

Those functions are your options for sending `Intent`s. `startActivity` and the `startService`/`bindService` functions use explicit `Intent`s; `sendBroadcast` does not.

Notice that `startActivity` throws an exception if it can't find your `Intent`'s target class, and `startService` will return `null` if it can't find your target class. `sendBroadcast` doesn't do anything like that because it doesn't even look at that field. `sendBroadcast` "Broadcasts the given intent to **all** interested BroadcastReceivers."

Since you are using `Context.sendBroadcast()` to send your intent, you should be setting an action on your `Intent` and your `BroadcastReceiver` should have an intent filter containing an entry for that action.

Comment: Is this correct?
In the docs it says this about intent:
"An intent that explicitly names a target component will activate that component; the filter doesn't play a role"

Comment: Hi Aaron,
I've updated my original post with some intent-filter and setAction changes. But its still not working.

Comment: That's because you're using different actions; the strings naming the action need to be identical! If you send an action "PROGRESS", then your manifest's tag should be <action android:name="PROGRESS" />